# How does Thunderbird's Mail Account Setup Wizard work?

Tags: email, account, thunderbird

I'm solving basically the same problem of "how do I map name+email address+password to IMAP and/or SMTP". Clearly, Thunderbird's got this one solved or near solved.

I can hunt through their source code, but is there any documentation on how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the account autoconfiguration documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration